# Flame attribute for cycles smoke not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to make a realistic smoke simulation in Cycles: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSiV5gg_lCs

I followed his node setup to a T, yet when I plug in the flame attribute into the emission node, my uv sphere doesn't light up like in the tutorial.

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

The problem was that I was changing the Smoke Domain object to Flow Type: Fire + Smoke instead of the emitter object, the UV sphere.